# How to upload Gitlab code coverage custom tool report baseline to the target branch?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

Our project tests have monitoring functionality that generates a report after test execution. Right now this report is exposed as an artifact, but I'd like to show it as a code quality report.

I created a script that creates gl-code-quality-report.json based on the test report and added this script to the after_script section. This will apply to multiple test jobs we have in our MR pipeline. All of them generate quality reports that should be merged in the end.

```
***
script:
    - bash ./run-test
after_script:
  - bash ./prepare-code-quality-report
  artifacts:
    when: always
    paths:
      - output
    expire_in: 72 hours
    reports:
      junit: output/junit.xml
      codequality: gl-code-quality-report.json
```

Job logs say that the report is successfully found and uploaded, but MR CodeCoverage widget shows `No code quality issues found.` According to documentation, it's because the target branch has no report that can be used as a baseline.

What I don't understand is how to upload this baseline. I would like the target branch to use the last merged MR quality report as a baseline, but I can't find any documentation on how to achieve that and it doesn't seem to be working OOTB. Could you please point me towards the documentation I'm missing or advice on how to achieve what I want? Thank you

Comment: You just need to upload a report from  a successful pipeline on your default branch. In other words: just run the same job on your default branch and make sure the whole pipeline finishes and is successful.

Answer (score 0):

If the documentation is correct about the root cause of your issue being the absence of baseline on default branch, then, just as systech said, make sure that your pipeline runs *successfully* at least once on your default branch.

That will create a report artifact associated with your default branch ref, which will then be used as a baseline to show changes in the MR UI.

In order to add branch pipelines to your project, you could leverage the `workflow: rules` keyword in your CICD config yaml file.

Here is an example where branch pipelines are allowed only on Merge requests and on the default branch, (without duplicate pipelines in case of both MR and branch pipelines being triggerable).

I even added a restrictive option to limit to merge commits to the default branch, although it is not robust to merge commits messages being different to the default value.

```
workflow:
  rules:
    - if: $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "merge_request_event"
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH && $CI_OPEN_MERGE_REQUESTS # prevents duplicate MR/branch pipelines
      when: never
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == $CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH   [ && $CI_COMMIT_MESSAGE =~ /^Merge branch .../ # or use whatever the default commit message is for merges  ] # Only if you want restrictive option on merges
```

I should also point out that the `artifacts` keyword should be at the same indentation level as `script` and `after_script` keywords.